# What is the semantics of return values of assignment functions?

Tags: mpfr

In MPFR's documentation (both HTML and PDF) I cannot find the semantics of return values of [assignment functions](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Assignment-Functions). For example, what is the meaning of return value of `mpfr_set`?

---

Extra: quite surprised that MPFR's initialization functions return `void`. So, if initialization fails, then the program will `gmp_die()` leading to `abort()`. What if in case of MPFR's initialization failure one needs the program running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like for most functions, the return value of the assignment functions is the [ternary value](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#ternary-value).

Note that initialization will never fail, except in case of out of memory; but in this case, the abort instead of an error is due to a limitation of GMP, on which MPFR is based. To keep the program running, catching `SIGABRT` might be a solution (or use your own memory allocation functions via GMP's custom allocation), but the data structures of GMP and MPFR are in an indeterminate state, so that it may be very difficult to recover, if not impossible: as the GMP manual says in [Custom Allocation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Custom-Allocation):

> There's currently no defined way for the allocation functions to recover from an error such as out of memory, they must terminate program execution. A longjmp or throwing a C++ exception will have undefined results. This may change in the future.

Basically, you would need a separate process and a way to transfer the data (possibly shared memory).

Comment: I've figured out that MPFR and GMP depends on I/O functions e.g. `fprintf` even if debugging / assertions disabled. I think this is because in case of problem GMP (perhaps MPFR too) use "abort rather than return" strategy. As a result: (unwanted) dependency on the I/O functions.

Comment: FYI: similar "dependency issue" with newlib: https://sourceware.org/pipermail/newlib/2023/020683.html .

Comment: @pmor MPFR and GMP depend on I/O functions just because they provide functions with I/O, e.g. `mpfr_out_str` for MPFR. I don't think that there have been requests to have this optional. The dependency on the formatted output functions is normally optional (i.e. only if `HAVE_STDARG` is defined).